# Como atualizar valor do context ao voltar para a página com react native?

Tags: react-native

Estou usando o context para passar os dados para as páginas, mas, quando eu volto uma página e altero o valor que tem no context, e depois sigo a diante para a outra página, a página não atualiza com os novos valores.
Podem me ensinar a lógica para assim que eu navegar para a página, ela atualizar os dados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver com o useFocusEffect() do React-Navigation que atualiza  os dados passado nele assim que a página recebe o foco.